# Unable to attach http health check to a https backend service on gcloud (cli)

Tags: gcloud, internal-load-balancer

Is it possible to during the backend service (https) creation attach it to a http health-check?

I'm asking that because if I try that manually (google cloud web console), I'm able to do it.

My script is the following:

```
gcloud compute http-health-checks create my-health-check --port 80 \
--host <my host goes here> \
--project "$PROJECT"`enter code here`

gcloud compute backend-services create my-bs \
--http-health-checks my-health-check \
--protocol HTTPS \
--timeout 5m \
--project "$PROJECT" \
--global
```

And I get the following error:

```
This HTTPS/HTTP2 backend service supports HealthCheck and HttpsHealthCheck
```

But if I create manually it the google (web console) allows me.

Comment: This can happen you create a backend with `protocol HTTPS` but you try to attach an `http-health-check`. You need to either create a `health-check` (as you did below) or create an `https-health-check`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
gcloud compute health-checks create http my-health-check --port 80 --host my-url --project "$PROJECT" 

gcloud compute backend-services create bs --health-checks my-health-check --protocol HTTPS --timeout 5m --project "$PROJECT" --global
```